# Uploaded File not showing in asp.net web api controller

Tags: asp.net, angular

I am trying to build simple image upload program and it's not working 
my code as follows . if anyone can figure this out it will be life saving for me
thanks

**here is my angular service**

```
 postFiles(caption: string, filetouplaod: File) {

    const headerss = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': this.globalsr.PrimaryTocken
    })

    let file: File = filetouplaod;

    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
    return this._http.post(`${this.globalsr.PrimaryAPI}Uploader/UploadSingleImage`, formData, {headers:headerss})
}
```

**Auth token**

private _primaryTocken: string = "Bearer ansKFMPonKyab-TBmgQAThXNKoSAt8ZHej31-Is1a0X0wo5iSIjiaXvRdHscyr9J3v3iG3PTg8_BnoZaiMRCEY03zAONYrKppp1ZdSAgGenMcqeW-UYyKKkOEk7UhXO3l1_-9kXc9rBnekuOIqCrH8TfbcF_G_hgUVFS2N8omQYetJ-VobtaW8n-8AZL72wigGeckLtjZhm12aEEwxsDxnrrY4WA0kB3T9eNURvSO_9lwjJ2_oBRwOPojcAh-dfrlOln0DkSpYL8F2Si2Od63pesFnMZ9uhBkYjZvWCfeN0k8-V7jvBLae_Pz_ljoYM1rVRF-CXwQgBOKiKmSi9h65DUAsqaQY8gLXb69xqPmomscXLn4yVwsdkNyZlayuVlL3EhQgjslgss6xqiUw36SPSsfTN9rMmRQr3dpiJogn61U7kF5FqCRAhmjj_JPOo8aXoh1EGkov0ArerB6lgMDvt3UM_f8-Dzi0i8vtZrstg" ;

**My Web api Controller**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadSingleImage")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadSingleImage()
    {
        var exMessage = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string uploadPath = "~/content/upload";
            HttpPostedFile file = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Get("file");
            }
            // Check if we have a file
            if (null == file)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
                {
                    error = true,
                    message = "Image file not found"
                });

            // Make sure the file has content
            if (!(file.ContentLength > 0))
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
                {
                    error = true,
                    message = "Image file not found"
                });

            if (!Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uploadPath)))
            {
                // If it doesn't exist, create the directory
                Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uploadPath));
            }

            //Upload File
            file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"{uploadPath}/{file.FileName}"));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { error = true, message = exMessage == string.Empty ? "An unknown error occured" : exMessage });
    }
```

but the case is this file count is zero all the time.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count
```

so I've send the exact data using postman and web api method works fine.
any ideas please

Comment: Hi, I have identical problem, did you findout how to done it?

Comment: OK, I fixed it - answer below

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` - just remove it.
Generaly after it I removed `Content-Type` in all my requests and replaced it by `'Accept': 'application/json'`.

Answer (score -1):

file is not able to get the file you are trying to upload from file input element. Use cosole log to check contents of filetouplaod.

```
 let file: File = filetouplaod;
```

Lets say fileInput is the input element, then you should assign something like this `filetouplaod = fileInput.files[0]`

Comment: Thanks for the comment but  this is the service method i posted here. i am sending the relevant file from the calling method. i log it and it was showing fine

Comment: I'm sure that he is doing it step before entering to function - look at parameters of function. For me not nesecary is `let file: File = filetouplaod;` as we have parameter of method.